# How (using web UI) or where ( in which file) would I be adding java option in an IBM HTTP Server?

Tags: ibmhttpserver

Thank you for sparing time to read the below query.

I want to know how (using a web UI)? or in where ( which file )? would I be able to add java option on an IBM HTTP Server.

Thanks!

Comment: Might you mean WebSphere Application Server? As @covener says, IBM HTTP Server is not Java at all, it's an IBM version of Apache httpd.

Answer (score 1):

IBM HTTP Server doesn't run inside of a JVM, so you won't find anyplace to add java options.

Comment: Then how can I add a java option?

Comment: You can't add one, it's not all applicable.